# Angular JS : Dynamically adding and removing rows in html

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have been trying to implement a page on HTML which integrates with Angular JS, basically to add/remove rows dynamically in a table. I have used the splice function to remove a row. There are 3 issues which I'm facing.

1. When I add a new row after deleting the last row, it gets populated with recently removed data.
2. If I remove the 2nd last row and add a new row again, the new row gets populated with the previous last row's data. Also, when I try to edit the row, both the last and 2nd last row's value gets changed simultaneously.
3. If I add blank rows and remove them using splice, they still remain in the array because when I submit the data to DB, I can see blank records.

I'm quite new to Angular. So, any help is appreciated.

HTML :

```
<div class="form-group" ng-repeat="item in details track by $index">
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <select class="form-control" ng-model="DetailsName[item.id]" required>
                                            <option>Dropdown 1</option>
                                            <option>Dropdown 2</option>                                             
                                        </select>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-7">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="Details[item.id]" required>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-1 ">
    <button class="remove " ng-show="!$first " ng-click="removeDetails($index) ">-</button>
  </div>
</div>
<button type="button " class="btn " ng-click="addDetail() ">Add Detail</button>
</div>
```

JS :

```
$scope.details = [{id:'detail1'}];
$scope.addDetail = function(){
    var newItemNo = $scope.details.length+1;
    $scope.details.push({'id':'detail'+newItemNo}); 
};

$scope.removeDetails = function (index) {
    $scope.details.splice(index,1);
  };
```

Comment: Try change your splice per pop. It’s recommended uses an hidden id.

Comment: @FabioNoth that really makes no sense

Comment: The `splice()` should work fine. What are you actually submitting?

Comment: Sorry, I’m typing by cellphone

Comment: I think that your array in control class want to control your array. And before drop data, try to push your index Id. And send a pop() item with your id. it’s more easier.

Comment: @charlietfl .. There are 2 submissions - one is a value from down and other is a text input.

Comment: @FabioNoth ... wouldn't pop always remove the last item ? I want to be able to delete any row I want ?

Comment: @LahaulSeth I mean are you sending the array or sending `DetailsName` object?

Comment: `pop()` makes no sense .... just ignore that whole concept. Yes it always removes last element in array which is not practical here

Comment: @charlietfl .. I'm sending the object ... it's actually supposed to connect to Java in the backend via a web service call from Angular JS ... The webservice call is only made the when the form is submitted though ..

Comment: What confuses me is that if I add a row and put some data and remove it and add a new row again it comes back ... I'm guessing there is an issue with either splice or push or maybe both ...

Comment: Actually think problem is using the array length to make the id and not using an incremental counter. When you change array the object properties can be over written and you can also end up with duplicate id's

Comment: Think of it this way. Start with 2 items in array. `detail1` and `detail2`. Now delete first and then add another. Will have both being `detail2`

Comment: Ok ... would you have a link for such an example ?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem has to do with the way you’re generating IDs.

```
var newItemNo = $scope.details.length+1;
```

You start with one item. Its ID is `detail1`. Adding an item creates `detail2`. Adding another creates `detail3`.

Now what happens when you remove `detail2`? You’re left with `[‘detail1’, ‘detail3’`]. What happens when you add a new item now?

Since the array length is 2, and 2 + 1 = 3, the added item becomes `detail3`. You have two `detail3`s!

Does that make sense? Oddly enough, I ran across this exact same problem a couple of months ago. And it was also an AngularJS app. (Though it could happen just as easily with any framework.)

Comment: thanks. I have now changed the implementation to only deleting the last row. I had tried to use a independent counter. However that seems to go out of control when the users repeatedly add and remove rows. Now the issue that I have is if add a data to the last row and remove it and add it back again the data reappears. Here's the fiddle link - http://jsfiddle.net/rnnb32rm/2663/. Works fine on the fiddle but not on my local PC. Any ideas ?

Comment: I have found the issue .. seems data is getting inserted into the Java HashMap when the user makes an entry which is why they keep coming back ... No issue with Angular JS ...